# Viewstate on asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, viewstate

I am a little confused about how Viewstate actually help the server controlls to store their data and retrieve it in the next postBack, I think a small example with  or  contoller should be ok.

by the way, html elements can't use the Viewstate?

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation, e.g. [Taking a Bite Out of ASP.NET ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972427.aspx)